# i have a arraylist where i am verifying particular object is existing or not but even it exists it always returns false

Tags: java

hi i have class called userdata which returns the Userarraylist which is of type User. when ever i try to use contains method to check particular property is existing or not it always returns false why?

Actually i want the array list to be generic which should return the objects that are set in array list.

```
String className = data.getUserData().get(0).getClass().getSimpleName();

if(className.equalsIgnoreCase("User")) {
   ArrayList<User> userdata=new ArrayList(); 
   userdata = data.getUserData();
   System.out.println(data.getUserData().contains(u.getUserId())); 

   if(userdata.contains(u.getUserName())) {
      System.out.println(userdata.get(0).getEmailId()); 
   }
}
```

Comment: So your programs look like the [jquery.min](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js) file?

Answer (score 4):

The ArrayList is of Users while you are checking to see if it contains an ID or String.

```
userdata.contains(u);
```

Comment: @RaghavenderReddy No. It contains users.

Comment: List<User> userdata = new ArrayList<User>();

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, the `ArrayList` contains `Objects`, not the id's of those objects.

You are trying to compare the `u.getUserId` to the objects within the list, this is not a valid comparison (User != int)

**UPDATE**

```
boolean contains = false;
for (User user : userdata) {
    // assuming userID is a number!!
    if(user.getUserId() == u.getUserId()) {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to know which properties are existing in the array list can i achieve this?

Comment: [`List.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) compares the object you pass to the objects in the list and will return true if `o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)` (that is the two objects must be equal).  The best way to achieve this with what you have is to walk the list comparing the `getUserId` of the objects in the list wiht `u.getUserId()`

Comment: i tried in this way   for (User users1 : userdata) {
                if (userdata.contains(users1.getEmailId()) ){
                  System.out.println("Name: " );
                }
              } even it is not working

Comment: I've added a possible solution

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note, you should use either the `instanceof` operator or `Class.equals` method, instead of getting the simple name name checking for equality with some string.

Comment: i want to get the properties stored in arraylist i dont want values ,suppose my user class is having 10 properties but in my arraylist i added only 3 properties among them ,i want to know what properties i added in array list

Answer (score 0):

You can't use contains in the list with `User` objects with its attributes i.e. `user.userId` or `user.email`.

Better to override `equals` method in `User` class which compare the attributes as below:

```
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      User other = (User) obj;
      if (userId == null) {
         if (other.userId != null)
        return false;
      } else if (!userId.equals(other.userId))
           return false;
      if (userName == null) {
         if (other.userName != null)
            return false;
      } else if (!userName.equals(other.userName))
        return false;
     return true;
    }
```

and then use `contains` as

```
   userdata.contains(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like
`userdata.get(SOME_INDEX).getUserName.equals(u.getUserName());`

or if you want to scan the whole ArrayList use this line inside a for loop

```
for (User user : userdata) {

    if(user.getUserName().equals(u.getUserName())) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that I have assumed there is a getter for the username attribute